# WPF Dynamic Cloning and Property Changing Of Controls

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

#### Summary

I am confused about how exactly to spawn multiple instances of the same control and then apply an animation to them.
[Here's](https://storage.googleapis.com/replit/images/1616003214840_05557acf4ab4cc77568d5a995d64bea4.gif) a example of what I'm trying to achieve (watch the click effects)

#### Current Approach

I have 2 "predefined" controls (TextLabel and Rectangle) which respectively serve the "+1" text and the image.
On click, I set the position of those to the mouse and begin the animation, which then animates them relative to the cursor position into some direction and then fades (like what's shown in the gif)

This is a good and functional approach, but it leaves something to be desired:
**How to make more than one of these pairs appear and animate at once?**

#### My problem

This is not trivial. Cloning the controls and then applying the same animation to them as the "original, dummy" ones causes issues with Z-Ordering and conflicts between Storyboards.
This "cloning" approach also seems very naive and inefficient.

#### So...

How to replicate that wonderful, cookie click effect with the text and small cookie image bouncing from the cursor... With more than one "pair" of those effects at once?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved by superimposing a non-hittestable `Canvas` control with a transparent `Background` on top of the entire `Window`.

> Window.xaml, pseudocode

```xml
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <Canvas IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
        <(Rest of content)/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then it's a matter of storing all active animated cookies and drawing them.

> Window.xaml.cs, pseudocode

```cs
internal class CookieCanvas : Canvas {
   
   private Vector2[] _cookiePositions;
   
   protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext) {
      foreach(var cookiePosition in _cookiePositions)
      {
          drawingContext.DrawImage(someCachedCookieImage, 
              new Rect(cookiePosition.X, cookiePosition.Y, img.PixelWidth, img.PixelHeight)
          );
      }
      
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply generate an image with the particles once and for all. You create two instances of that image and you rotate them in opposite directions. The images of course are transparent where there is no particle. The cookie image can be put on top of this by a simple animation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am however not seeking a runtime and hardcoded solution and need (theoretically) infinite dynamically generated particles.